# How would you optimize this mysql query?

Tags: mysql

Can anybody help me in optimizing this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
A.X1,      
A.X2   
FROM TABLEAA A
JOIN TABLEBB B ON A.Y = B.Y AND B.Z1='SELECTED1' AND B.W NOT LIKE 'SLECTED3'
JOIN TABLECC C ON A.Y = C.Y AND C.Z2='SELECTED2'
AND A.W NOT LIKE 'SLECTED3'
```

WHEREAS

TABLEAA : 1 million entries
 TABLEBB : 17 million entries
 TABLECC : 1.2 million entries

It works but it takes almost 8 to 10 seconds.

Is there any other way to write this?

edit: primary index on TableBB is combination of B.Z1 and B.Y. primary index on TableCC is combination of C.Z2 and C.Y. primary index on TableAA is A.Y

Comment: Running `explain` on the query will show you missing indexes.

Comment: What are the indexes on the tables?

Comment: `B.Z1='SELECTED1'`, `NOT LIKE 'SLECTED3'` - I don't know what the heck are you doing, but this smells like a bad schema design.

Comment: @ Kickstart; primary index on TableBB is combination of B.Z1 and B.Y.
             primary index on TableCC is combination of C.Z2 and C.Y
             primary index on TableAA is A.Y

Comment: What does `explain` output?

Comment: @ Karoly Horvath; the selected1 and slected3 are different selection by user.
@ Vatev; What do you mean by output?

Comment: @wiki run `explain {YOUR_QUERY}` and post the results.

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` on what is clearly an equality operation? Is it something to do with case sensitivity?

Comment: Do you have an index on TableAA for column W? If not your query will read all 1m records and check each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this's better.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.X1, A.X2   
FROM TABLEAA AS A
INNER JOIN(TABLEBB AS B)
   ON(A.Y = B.Y)
INNER JOIN(TABLECC AS C)
   ON(A.Y = C.Y)
WHERE B.Z1 = 'SELECTED1' AND
      B.W NOT LIKE '%SLECTED3%' AND
      C.Z2='SELECTED2' AND
      A.W NOT LIKE '%SLECTED3%'
```

Comment: This will likely be substantially slower as the leading wildcars on B.W and A.W will render indexes on those columns useless. Without the wildcards it should be no different to the original query.